# Need help making a better code, this one is so ugly

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a query with the following data

```
85343
125242
65252
125655
185658
235758
```

Those are 24 hour times without the format. I tried parsing it with `HHmmss` to then give it the format `hh:mm:ss` a it kind of worked with the hours 12+ but with 12- it went to hell giving wrong times. I worked it out with the following code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("Hmmss");
DateFormat dateFormat21 = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
DateFormat dateFormat5 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");

System.out.println((Query.getString(1).length() == 5) ? 
        dateFormat5.format(dateFormat2.parse(Query.getString(1))) 
        : dateFormat5.format(dateFormat21.parse(Query.getString(1))));
```

it solves the problem with the time errors as I get the correct times

```
8:53:43AM 
12:52:42PM 
6:52:52 AM 
12:56:55 PM 
6:56:58 PM 
11:57:58PM
```

Is there anyway to make this better?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code *review*. Please ask your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: oh sorry didnt know about that site. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use two different `DateFormat` for parsing but only one :

```
DateFormat dateFormat21 = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
DateFormat dateFormat5 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
String s = Query.getString(1);
if (s.length()==5) s = "0"+s;
System.out.println(dateFormat5.format(dateFormat21.parse(s)));
```

But there's no real problem in your code apart calling `getString` more than necessary.

Comment: Ya, i wanted to solve it with a single line of code as i was going doing all the work inside the Mode.Addrow function and it escaped my mind to use a variable and work EVERYthing before actualy calling Addrow lol... Thanks for your aproach it will make the code easier to understand for some other people.

Comment: The missing "0" looks like an accident (was the string converted to a number somewhere in the communication ?). So it looks more logical to start with a fix of the string (adding the missing "0") and to apply only one dateFormat for the parsing.

Comment: well i cant go that far as the data is that way in the DB and i dont manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some regex like this:

```
(\d?\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)
```

Match group 1 is the hours, match group 2 the minute, match group 3 the seconds.

For more about regex in Java see here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: will try learning about this now... it kind of feel like something hard to get when u read it after 4 months u wrote that code tho :D. Thanks lucas